# Offline puppet agent installation from puppet master- Opensouce Puppet

Tags: yum, puppet

I need to perform offline installation of puppet agents on 300+ servers.
Servers vary in architecture and design and have no access to internet.
 Kindly suggest the best way to achieve this given puppet server has access internet

Answer (score 0):

There are two common approaches to installing a package on a server with no internet connectivity.

1. Create a golden image with package already installed

   - [pxe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment)
   - [red hat create pxe image](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19902-01/html/821-1367/gisti.html)
2. Use a local package repository

   - [create offline package repo](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/308983)
   - [pulp package repository](http://www.pulpproject.org/)
   - [spacewalk package repository](http://spacewalk.redhat.com/)
   - [katello](http://www.katello.org/docs/user_guide/puppet_integration/index.html)

Likely it would be best to use a combination of these solutions. Create an OS image that contains the puppet agent installed, and / or include an apt or yum repository that is pointed to your local repo server (pulp, spacewalk).

One other option would be to download the package locally, and ssh it to every machine.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89222/how-to-download-a-file-from-repo-and-install-it-later-w-o-internet-connection